# Inserting, deleting, and adding objects into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have not started coding this yet because I would like to gather my thoughts and figure out the best way to tackle this problem.

I have a sorted array that contains objects with a category and name.

- The array is sorted by category (the categories are A, B, and C). A will always be placed first before B and B will always be placed before C.
- After the categories are determined it will also be sorted by name. (Category A apple will be before category A banana)

Here is the method I was thinking of.

Have an inventory class which has 4 arrays in it. The arrays will be split up by category (array A, array B, array C and the combined array). This is so when the category is checked it will go to the correct array and place the content into the correct location based on the name. Instead of checking 1 huge array it checks a smaller array. When the object gets added it will append array a b and c into the combined array.

This will be coded in js. I am writing this because I want to know if I am on the right track or if there is better logic to sorting an array by category and name.

Comment: You have to provide at least some of your own code.  Try it before asking if something is a better way, typcially if you can get it to work and it's not a huge effort you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the sortings by the or operator. Through js short circuiting, that will be quite efficient, e.g.:

```
yourArray.sort((a,b)=>
      a.category.localeCompare(b.category)
   || a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fore more groups with the same comparing mechanism, like `localeCompare`, you could use an array with the keys. This is easy to maintain.

```
var keys = ['category', 'name'];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var v;
    return keys.some(function (k) {
        return v = a[k].localeCompare(b[k]);
    }) && v;
});
```